# How to select sector on NT3H2111 nfc chip

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am using an android phone to read and write some data to the EEPROM of a NT3H2111 nfc chip.

The method to change sector appears to be working, but never the less, the sector is not changed when i try to read the contents, it is still on sector zero.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        ntagHandler = new NtagHandler(tag);
        ntagHandler.connect();
        if(mode == AppMode.READ) {
            Ve95_DataModelHandler.readSectionNames(ve95DataModel, ntagHandler);
            populateView();
        } else if(mode == AppMode.WRITE) {
            populateDataModel();
            Ve95_DataModelHandler.writeSectionNames(ve95DataModel, ntagHandler);
        }
        ntagHandler.close();
        ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imageViewNFCConnect);
        if(img != null) {
            img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mode = AppMode.READ;
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Caught exception: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

...

```
public boolean sectorSelect(int sector) throws IOException {
    byte[] cmd_sel1 = { (byte)0xC2, (byte)0xFF };
    byte[] cmd_sel2 = { (byte)sector, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00 };
    byte[] result1 = nfca.transceive(cmd_sel1);
    if (result1 == null) {
        throw new TagLostException();
    } else if ((result1.length == 1) && ((result1[0] & 0x00A) == 0x000)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            byte[] result2 = nfca.transceive(cmd_sel2);
            if (result2 == null) {
                throw new TagLostException();
            } else if ((result2.length == 1) && ((result2[0] & 0x00A) == 0x000)) {
                // NACK response according to DigitalProtocol
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // passive ACK
            Log.d(TAG, "sectorSelect caught exception, but succeeded anyway");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
/*
 *  Read section names from EEPROM and put them into the data model
 */
public static boolean readSectionNames(@NonNull Ve95_DataModel ve95DataModel,
                                       @NonNull NtagHandler ntagHandler)
{
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Reading section names");
        boolean retVal = ntagHandler.sectorSelect((byte) 1);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("sectorSelect returned %b", retVal));
        byte[] data = ntagHandler.fastRead((byte) BASE_ADDRESS_SECTION_NAMES, (byte) 0x2C);
        Log.d(TAG, Utils.bytesToHex(data));
        byte[] subArray;
        int size = 16;
        for(int i=0; i < 20; i++) {
            subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, i * size, (i+1) * size);
            String name = new String(subArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            ve95DataModel.setSectionName(i, name);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("section %d name %s", i, name));
        }
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get this result, but from the data i can see that the sector is still zero, and have not been changed to sector one.

D/Ve95_DataModelHandler: Reading section names

D/: sectorSelect caught exception, but succeeded anyway

D/Ve95_DataModelHandler: sectorSelect returned true

D/Ve95_DataModelHandler: 04,B2,87,CA,D4,64,80,00,44,00,00,00,00....

Anyone know how to change the sector?

Regards

Henrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved it myself. A 1K chip was mounted instead of a 2K chip. No wonder it didn't work :)

Comment: Hello! What exactly is select_sector does? Am I supposed to select_sector before reading of writing operations? Thanks!

Comment: The NT3H2211 chip have 2k memory. From the NFC side this EEPROM memory is addressed in 4 byte blocks , which means that only 1K is addressable. Therefore the sector select is used to select either the upper or the lower 1K of the 2K memory :)

Comment: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NT3H2111_2211.pdf. Take a look at page 16